# Code won't execute unless cout is used

Tags: c++, compilation, console-application, compiler-optimization

I wrote a very simple program to see how it would behave when allocating many objects in memory.
It runs fine and will consume all of my computer's memory given enough time, unless the `cout` statement is removed. Without that line, the program will simply exit right after initialization. Why?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    long long test1[10];
    long long test2[10];
    long long test3[10];
    long long test4[10];
    long long test5[10];
};

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 500000; ++i)
    {
        new Test;
        new Test;
        new Test;
        new Test;

        std::cout << i << "\n"; // Program won't work as desired without this
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Setup: Visual Studio 2013, Release, x64, Static Crt

**Edit:** I posted this question in a hurry when at work, sorry for being careless. Now it's right.

Comment: How did you determine that this program "runs fine" without the `std::cout` statement?  What did you observe?

Comment: It runs just fine until it gets out of memory - http://goo.gl/oEd4uy

Comment: @DrewDormann Actually it runs fine _with_ `cout`. I edited the question, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy Nice tool! Well, I just checked there as well. Try commenting line 25 and you'll see what I was referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without** the `std::cout` line and **with** optimizations turned on, your compiler is determining that **there is a faster algorithm** that's equivalent to the logic you wrote.

The faster algorithm is *"do nothing"*.

---

Note: this is possible because your compiler is assuming that an "out of memory" scenario isn't a desired side-effect.  So a faster algorithm is valid, even if it lowers the likelihood of running out of memory.

Comment: Could you please comment on what can be done to prevent my "desired operation" from being optimized out, without actually having to turn off optimizations altogether?

Comment: If you don't turn off optimizations, then... they won't be turned off ! Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @kebs You misunderstand me. I want my program to allocate memory endlessly (just the code example - with the `cout` line), without turning optimization off for the entire program.

Comment: You need to tell the compiler to do something that he can't optimize away. One solution is to declare a variable as `register`, and then giving it a value in the for loop. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration. However, I can't guarantee it will work, as it seems the compiler can still optimize it. I know there is another way, but just can't remember...

Comment: @Marc.2377 your question in these comments could get a lot more attention if you [ask it as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  If you take that route, be sure to explain *why* you need full optimizations, because that's the tricky part.